# What is the proper way to get data out of Relay Modern's internal store?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relaymodern

We are currently exploring some of the undocumented apis in Relay Modern, and so far the best way we have found to grab data out of the Relay Store for use in the application is to call environment.lookup with a selector derived from a graphql query.

this happened because it seems like the RecordSource.get method returns the object from the store but doesn't fetch any data for nodes nested under it. Is there a better way to fetch an object and all connected nodes to it?

Our use case is we are using applyOptimisticUpdate to update Relay's store so that changes that are made prior to saving on our admin application are visible to all components that have requested that piece of data. So once we are done making these changes we'd like to requery the relay Store to get the current state of a record, clean it up for real mutation purposes, and send the updated payload to the server.

Any insights would be appreciated and I will add documentation to Relay with findings (if so desired).

Answer (score 2):

Relay exposes a `commitLocalUpdate` function, which takes the environment and an updater function as arguments. The updater works the same way as the ones you use in mutations -- it receives a proxy of the store which you can modify and return. You could use the body of this function to read data from the store and emit any side-effects you need.

It feels a bit like abusing the API though, so there's probably a more correct way of doing this.